# How to set up an Android project with Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

My professor and I are using different versions of Eclipse apparently and I'm having trouble matching his project requirements up to my Eclipse.

His requirements are: "You are recommended to use the 2.3 SDK and test your app on 4.0 emulators..."

I am using Juno and this is what I see:

[image: juno]

Is this set up right?

So that people don't just tell me to email my professor as an answer, what is the difference between target SDK and "compile with" conceptually? I'm unclear on why they are separate options.

How can I compile with 4.0 but have a lower target? That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your "compile with" level should not be higher than the target SDK level. (It's often the same as the minimum required SDK, but there are sometimes reasons to set it higher.) The idea for "compile with" is to allow you to target higher levels and restrict your API calls to a lower level for compatibility.

Otherwise, your choices look consistent with what the prof is recommending. Note that none of these settings have much to do with the emulator version. You set that when you create an AVD and as long as the emulator version is at least the "minimum required sdk", the project should run (barring bugs, of course).

Answer (score 2):

If you set your minimum reqd SDK to API:9 too then you'll be closer to what your teacher says.  What you have looks OK.